# Idea or reference for sample size calculation

Tags: bayesian, sample-size

I have a question about sample size calculations under the Bayesian setting, and would like either some ideas/suggestions, or reference papers that might help.

In general, my problem is as follows.  I have a population of computer parts of which some proportion of the parts will be defective. I would like, say, for no more than 1% of the parts to be defective. Here, I consider a part to be defective if the corresponding measured value $X$ > 10. Now, if I have, say, 1,000,000 of these computer parts then I could test 99% of them to see if the defect rate is higher than 1% (which I don't want to do). However, I want to only test a subset of the parts to be able to make the "no more than 1% defective parts claim" with some level of certainty.

Now, I would like to approach this problem from the Bayesian point-of-view, and assume that the distribution of measurements $X$ follows some distribution (say, Normal($\mu$, $\sigma^2$)) and associated prior $p(\mu,\sigma^2)$. Under the Bayesian paradigm how does one proceed with sample size estimation for this scenario? I.e., how do I choose a sample size such that I have some level of certainty that the $Pr(X>10) < 0.01$, for example.

Also, I don't want to treat the variable as binary since I do have continuous measurements $X$ that I can leverage.

Comment: Pretty much the only way to be certain that $Pr(X>10)<0.01$ is to choose the prior so that this holds, and then to not draw any sample, because the sample may always bring up observations with $X>10$ that can "spoil" this probability. I guess being "certain that $Pr(X>10)$ is whatever" is not what you really want to achieve, because in fact you want to *find out* what the data have to say about  $Pr(X>10)$, don't you?

Comment: @ChristianHennig Yes sorry. Perhaps certain is a bit loose here. Maybe it should have been more probabilistic. Like how can I choose the sample size such that the probability that Pr(X>10) < 0.01 is no larger than $1-\alpha$.  I basically want high probability that the statement is true.

Comment: I'm not an expert in Bayesian sample size calculations, however I think you want something like what you state in your comment above *assuming that indeed in your number of 1,000,000 parts the relative frequency of defective parts is at most* $\beta$, and note that $\beta$ may need to be smaller than 0.01, because if $\beta=0.01$, then it will probably not be possible to get the probability for $Pr(X>10)\ge 0.01$ arbitrarily small.

Comment: The baseline is (not sure whether you understand this already) that obviously you should only be able to get a high probability that your statement is true, if indeed there is only a less than 0.01 proportion of defective parts, otherwise not.

Comment: @ChristianHennig yes this makes sense to me but thank you for pointing  out the baseline.

Comment: If you have to collect data, you can never be *certain* in the ultimate result.

Comment: @whuber sorry, again perhaps certain is the wrong choice of word. I basically want to understand what are the available options for Bayesian sample size determination.

Comment: @whuber if more explicit details are needed please suggest what is needed and I can try to add them.

Comment: Could you indicate how you view them as any different than the options for non-Bayesian sample size determination?  That would help respondents focus on the issues that might be special to your circumstances.

Comment: @whuber you lost me

Comment: In general, there's no difference.  In all cases you have to make an assumption about the data you will obtain, formulate a probabilistic goal (such as "I want the posterior probability of the event $X\gt 10$ to be less than $0.01$"), compute those chances as a function of sample size $n,$ and solve for the smallest $n\gt 0$ that meets your goal.  Exactly how you do this depends on all the particulars, but even then the chief difference between Bayesian and traditional formulations is that--absent any conjugate prior--the calculations are much more complicated in the Bayesian setting.

Comment: @whuber I think that is where my confusion lies. I don't understand how the sample size n enters the picture. Once you have assumed a certain posterior form for the parameters, why would I need a sample size to make that probability calculation? Or is it the other way around and you assume a prior, generate pseudo data of size n, calculate teh posterior and then calculate that probability. In the latter, then I could see why sample size enters the picture.

Comment: The second scenario is right.  The idea is that as $n$ grows, the posterior ought to narrow down around a particular value.  Although you can't guarantee the results of the future data, this exercise gives you a quantitative sense of how much narrowing occurs as a function of $n.$  That, at least, relates uncertainty to sample size.  Everything flows from that.

Comment: @whuber thanks for the clarification! That makes sense to me. One remaining question I have is whether or not there is a standard way to think about simulating data. I suppose one way is to simulate data from the prior, and then to plug those parameter samples into teh likleihood to simulate data?

Answer (score 0):

From a Bayesian perspective, you just want to compute $P(X > 10)$ given a series of measurements of $X$. There may not exist a sample size for which $P(X>10)<0.01$ if $P(X>10)$ is *in fact* greater than 0.01! For example, you take 10,000 measurements of $X$ and they're all greater than 10. You'd have to have a pretty skewed prior to conclude $P(X>10)<0.01$. In general, $X>10$ is a binary event, and computing $P(X>10)$ is typically performed via a [Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Bayesian_inference). You can find an open source implementation of this exact functionality [here](https://finraos.github.io/model-validation-toolkit/docs/html/credibility.html#mvtk.credibility.prob_below), with an accompanying [introduction](https://finraos.github.io/model-validation-toolkit/docs/html/credibility_user_guide.html) and [tutorial](https://finraos.github.io/model-validation-toolkit/docs/html/notebooks/credibility/Credibility.html). While those are geared toward evaluating performance metrics, the same process applies to your problem.

**UPDATE**:
The pdf you cited is asking "Given a prior on $P(X>10)$, what sample size should I expect to need to verify that $P(X > 10) < 0.01$ with some higher degree of certainty (technically they're asking how many required to narrow margin of error of $P(X > 10)$ by some amount, but I think that's the best way to translate that source onto your problem). This effectively gives rise to a compound experiment:

1. Sample a possible P(X > 10) from the prior. [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Bayesian_inference)
2. Simulate hypothetical future samples until your posterior estimate of $P(X > 10)$ (prior combined with new synthetic samples) is less than 0.01. Record the number of synthetic samples you needed to reach that conclusion.
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 and build a histogram of how many synthetic samples you needed.

From there, you could pick the most common number of samples needed, or the upper $\alpha$ quantile of your histogram of samples (i.e. $\alpha$ chance that this sample size will be sufficient to establish $P(X > 10) < 0.01$ with some threshold of certainty). The pdf you linked seems to effectively describe ways to streamline that procedure combined with different ways to extract a sample size from that histogram. But I think the core concept is accurately outlined with the above experiment.

---

That said, this may or may not be the *optimal* approach to your particular problem. If you have to set out funding for a large, expensive, time consuming study ahead of time, sure you'd want to try to figure out what sample size you'd need to verify a claim expected to be true to some greater degree of certainty than you have. However, if you can get feedback as you go, you could effectively just run one real experiment instead of a large $N$ synthetic ones from step 1 above. That is, just keep measuring parts until your posterior estimate (as described in my first answer) of $P(X > 10) < 0.01$ falls below your chosen threshold of certainty.

[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Bayesian_inference) In the paper, this would be a distribution implied from a previous study. In your example, it's your best idea of what the distribution of $P(X > 10)$ is. You'd typically use a beta distribution for this as described above. For example, if you recall having witnessed 10 working parts, and one nonfunctional one, you could use Beta(10, 1). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_smoothing#Pseudocount for an overview of this heuristic. This distribution represents your uncertainty of $P(X > 10)$, but since it's expressed as a probability distribution, you can sample it. This simulates possible real world values of $P(X > 10)$ based on your current understanding.

Comment: Maybe I'm not being clear in my question. This is just a sample size question before collecting any data. How many samples do I need to collect to feel sufficiently confident that the true defect rate is < 0.01 (maybe it is, maybe it isn't). Is it, 10?, 100, all 1,000,000? Frequentist do this all the time with power calculations, but I don't see how to do this from the Bayesian point-of-view.

Comment: I think you're confusing p values with an estimate of a statistic. Frequentists compute the probability of results "at least as extreme" (for some definition of extreme left to the statistician) as the ones observed occurring from a random sample. That's all a p-value is. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misuse_of_p-values for more on that. Bayesians try to quantify their certainty of possible values of parameters like P(X>10) using probability distributions. They would therefore attempt to compute P(P(X > 10) < 0.01) in a justifiable way.

Comment: The point of my question isn't to do what frequentist do, but to understand how the Bayesian does sample size determination. I think you are missing my point. There has to be a way to choose the sample size such that some criteria is satisfied. That is what I need help with and or wanted suggestions for. Check out a book on Bayesian reliability and you'll see plenty of Bayesian sample size calculations.

Comment: The first thing I get when I google "Bayesian reliability" is https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/apr/section4/apr46.htm, which does not mention sample size calculations. Is there a particular reference you had in mind?

Comment: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-77950-8

Comment: Not a reliability paper, but here is another example: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ba/1340370548

Comment: Thanks for the links. I was able to access the second one. I can see how I wasn't quite addressing your question. I skimmed the paper, but I was careful to make sure I understood the problem setting and verified the Bayesian approach I described in my update seemed to be in line with the approaches described in the paper. I then attempted to map it on to your problem and concluded with a shortcut you may be able to take given potential differences between your problem setting and that of clinical trials.

Comment: Thanks for looking into that. Can you elaborate on the connection between step 1) and step 2)? I don't seem to understand what it means to sample possible P(X > 10) from the prior.

Comment: I updated the answer with a footnote on priors and sampling from them in your case. Step one gives you a potential real value of P(X>10). Step 2 gives you random examples of parts failing or not given that potential real value of P(X>10).

Comment: I don't want to treat the variable as binary,

Comment: X isn't binary. X > 10 is binary. If you ultimately care about X > 10, the underlying distribution of X becomes less relevant in that you're just going to integrate it to 10 to capture P(X > 10).

Comment: So you are placing a  prior on the probability, i.e., a prior for P(X > 10)?

Comment: Correct, the random variable you care about is a binary outcome: X > 0. You're interested in P(X > 10 is True) or P(X > 10) for short. You're not sure what it is, but you have some background knowledge so you place a prior over it etc. BTW, if you have absolutely no background knowledge at all, or wish to make as few assumptions as possible, pick one with the highest entropy. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_maximum_entropy for discussion. For variables on the interval [0, 1] (like P(X>10)), this would be a uniform distribution over [0, 1], which is equivalent to Beta(1, 1).

Comment: If that's the case, wouldn't it be simpler to jut write it as  $Y \sim\text{ Bin}(n, theta)$, $p(\theta)\sim\text{Beta}(a,b)$, and then just vary $n$  and calculate $E[\theta|Y]$ in closed form? No simulation needed. Then we can check $E[\theta|Y]$  or a credible interval to  see if its < 0.01.

Comment: Sure, I think you get the idea